# How can i create an online bot that click on a script?

Tags: bots

I have created a script in php (on altervista, so it's an online code) but i want to run it every 55 minutes. How can i will realize it? 
I have searched on internet but i hadn't find something.
It's important, please.
Thanks
only free solutions, i have only find a service but it isn't free...
Sorry for my english but i'm french!

Comment: can you explain what is "online bot that click on a script"?

Comment: I have to click on this link: mypage.altervista.org/checkloop.php every 55 minute each days to take some statistic, how can i do it?

Comment: you can create a simple script that makes an http request, run it in a infinite loop and make it sleep every 55 seconds or use a cronjob if you have a linux machine

Comment: i have a windows machine, how can i create a simple script that makes an http request? can you give me che code? please...

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this goal you will need a "dedicated" machine
you can use your machine but it is need to be turned on all the time (no sleep, hibernate and etc) the process need to run always, that's a dedicated server like Amazon, Azure, Google cloud and such will be the best solution

if you are using a linux operation system you can take advantage of the system cronjob and run the script periodically (every n seconds/minutes... or at specific date) 
another option is to run the script in a infinte loop and make it sleep every n seconds or so, this will be valid both on linux and on other operation system that don't support periodically job in such a straight forward manner like windows

a simple script in python using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module could be something like

```
import requests
from time import sleep

while True:
    try:
        response = requests.get("http://mypage.altervista.org/checkloop.php")
        print(response.text)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    sleep(55) #sleep 55 seconds
```

but this can easily achieve in any language...

to run this script on any instance you can use

```
python path_to_script.py >> path_to_log_file.log 2>&1 &
```

some explanation

- `python` is the python cmd to run `py` files
- `>>` append the script's output to a file (log file)
- `2>&1` append `stderr` to `stdout` meaning that all errors also will be appended to the log file
- `&` run the process in the background so it will run even when the user triggered this will log out from the machine

you can use a more robust approach using linux's `cron job`
and use the cmd `crontab -e` to edit the crontab file and set the following task

```
*/5 * * * * python path_to_script.py >> path_to_outputfile.log 2>&1
```

this will run the script every five minutes (and append stdout and stderr to output log file)

**Note** that in this case the script itself doesn't need a `while loop` but to run only once, the system (`cron job`) will deal with the frequents runs

A useful info on linux's cron job can be found [here](https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/)

Comment: ok, thanks. I have create an account on dedicate server on amazon cloud. Now, How can i create the script?

Comment: copy this script and try to run it, see if it gives you the desired functionality, if so just run the script with `&` at the end to run process in background, I've edit the script to not crush under errors

Comment: ok, but i have a problem. When i started the instances of amazon linux, there isn't python or something. It's an empty machine. 1)How can i create a script using python if i haven't it? 2)how can i create a task to run the script infinitely? thanks

Comment: @John, hi, 1) not possible... almost any linux distribution is coming with python installed, in case it's not just install it using `apt-get` more details can be found on this site...
2) added a related section in my answer, hope this will help, let me know if you have more questions

Comment: so, i found crontab on linux machine but when i sent the command to open the folder "cron.hourly" it said me "permission denied". I tried chmod 700 and sudo but it doesn't work. why? thanks

Comment: @John, I never had problems with cronjob, basically every user has it's own and you can edit it using `crontab -e` you better look for this site for the answer or post a question regarding your issue

Comment: ok thanks. Sorry but i have the last one question. How can i install on virtual machine xdg and open an url? it said me "command not found" but i have on machine the version 3.4. Thanks a lot

Comment: @John I don't understand exactly what is your error, you better open a new question thread about this and provide all the necessary code and errors, I'll try to help you there also, but others (more experience) will see it too